# Browser MMORPG basics ideas

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I started making a MMORPG to improve my web design skills. I managed to make users able to move around the screen and get some items with a combination of Javascript, PHP and MySQL.

I want to show all logged users at the same time moving around and push info to the user on what the others I doing but I have no idea how to do it. What are the general ideas/methods to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Don't.  This is incredibly impractical in php, javascript and mysql.  You need a language like Java to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically create a table called "online" with two columns "ID,Time" and whenever a player does some action it updates "Time" that's for the logging part.

And you get a cron job to check the database and if the Time in the database is greater than the current time minus (for example) -5 minutes (timing out time) DELETE the row.

Comment: Thanks I'll start doing that right now! And do you know how I can check the database constantly for player actions? or push updates in the database to the player? Thanks

Comment: You can save the player ID in $_SESSION['id'] for example and when the player moves or does some action -using ajaxRequest- get action.php

`<?
session_start();
$ID = $_SESSION['id'];
if(isset($ID)){
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `online` WHERE `ID` = '$ID';");
$isOn = mysql_affected_rows();
//check if the ID is in the database already
if($isOn !== '0'){
mysql_query("UPDATE `online` SET `time` = '$time' WHERE `ID` ='$ID';");
}else{
//if not already in the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `online` (`time` ,`ID` )VALUES ('$time', '$ID');");
}
}else{
//do something
}
?>

Comment: And cron.php running everytime someone requests any page, and it checks every row in the table "online" if that "Time" Value is later than lets say 5 minutes ago, consider the user offline.

Comment: thanks a lot I already started doing it! What happens if I check the database once a couple of seconds for updates? It seems the easier way to do it but do you know if it may cause any kind of problem? or idk any cons it could have. Thanks

Comment: For updating the user status/time, it is no harm.

But the cron job might be a problem for using extensive resources if you have alot of users {rows in the database}.
So you better throttle it and instead of running it with every request you can run it via cron job every 3 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this engine to accomplish what you want: [MMO.js](http://mmojs.org)... it allows you to build real-time MMORPGs in JavaScript using websockets =)